# Vue.js component to display password field

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Let's say, I have

```
<input type="text">
```

I want to allow user to enter password inside this input.

**Problem:** how to display one value and to store another?

To display modified value is very simple:

```
// when user is inside input
valueEncrypted() {
            let s = "";
            for(let i = 0; i < this.value.length; i++) {
                if(i === this.value.length - 1) {
                    s += this.value[i]; //show last character types
                } else {
                    s += "*";
                }
            }
            return s;
        }

  // when user is outside of input
   s += "*"; // only this line is left inside loop
```

But how to store one value (`"password"`) and display another (`"*******d"`) *inside* input field.

Comment: Do you realize that using `type="password"` has important security and feature implications? For example, browsers can store the password and it will never autocomplete. Please do not create/use any half-baked solution that will cripple the browser and the user.

Comment: I understand, but how can I accomplish this task using `type="password"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take advantage of the [fact](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Form-Input-Components-using-Custom-Events) that `<input v-model="something">` is just syntactic sugar for

```
<input v-bind:value="something" v-on:input="something = $event.target.value">
```

So with this you can write a component, where you can pass the vue instance variable and modify it inside the component, I have created a similar component :

```
Vue.component('passoword', {
  template: '\
    <input type="text" v-model="localVar"  @keyup="addPass">\
  ',
  props: ['value'],
  data: function() {
    return {
      localVar: this.value
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addPass: function(event) {
      let LocalVal = this.value + event.key
      this.$emit('input', LocalVal)
      let s = "";
      for (let i = 0; i <= LocalVal.length; i++) {
        if (i === LocalVal.length) {
          s += LocalVal[i-1]; //show last character types
        } else {
          s += "*";
        }
      }
      this.localVar = s
    }
  }
})
```

You can see it's demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mimani/w9wf128L/).

---

You can also also look at this [link](https://css-tricks.com/better-password-inputs-iphone-style/) for an alternate approach.

Comment: No, I need exactly what's described in question.

Comment: @JacksonJ Can you tell me what is thing this solution is not providing?

Comment: I want to show last typed character while user is entering his password

Comment: You saved my day!